# Tapestry internationalization - removing locale prefix

Tags: internationalization, tapestry

Tapestry adds automatically a locale prefix to the URL when switching between locales:

```
http://host/en/home
http://host/es/home
http://host/fr/home
```

etc.
How to avoid it; I found in the Tapestry APi that you should add additional configuration to the AppModule class:

```
configuration.add(SymbolConstants.ENCODE_LOCALE_INTO_PATH, "false");
```

and use LinkCreationListener2 or LinkCreationListener(for Tapestry < 5.2*) on your own. Can anyone give more info or example? Thks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do in terms of tracking the locale.  Tapestry 5.0 uses a cookie to track locale; Tapestry 5.1 switched to encoding it into the path. I think in the path is correct ... after all, if a user bookmarks the french version of the page, they should see the french version of the page a month later when they use the bookmark.

Plan:

- Override the symbol to "false"
- Contribute a RequestFilter to the RequestHandler pipeline that reads a cookie to set the value
- Override the PersistentLocale service to store the cookie

Comment: Hi Howard, thanks you for your response. Unfortunately I find nothing neither in Tapestry User guide/tutorial nor in documentation how to achieve what you advise to do; i.e. - Contribute a RequestFilter to the RequestHandler pipeline that reads a cookie to set the value and Override the PersistentLocale service to store the cookie. Any tips would be grateful :); Thanks.

Comment: All the stuff about contributing filters and such is covered in the Tapestry IoC documentation. http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-ioc-configuration.html It is assumed that you understand how the IoC approaches configurations and overrides: there's a single approach in Tapestry and then all services of all flavors can do things the same way.